# VS Code SETUP for OS X 10.10.5

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can someone please help me on how I can download VS code on Mac OS X 10.10.5? I am unable to download it. Once I download the VS studio zip file, it says I cannot open it need the newer version of OS. Please help me.

Comment: Even the latest version of 10.10.5 is nearly four years old. I would assume that you have to search for a version that is compatible on your own - what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Download an older version from https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/.

On the left hand side you have navigation to the previous updates.

Alternatively update the OS (*a bit*).

*(Officially VS Code claim to support macOS 10.10+. )*

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the Jan2021 version because same thing was happening to me and I was able to successfully download and launch VS. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code v1.53 also appears to be the last version that works on OSX 10.11.6, which is the last version of OSX before Open GL was depreciated in favor of Metal graphics.
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53